# Problems with Post on android, always exception

Tags: android, post

Im trying to build a POST packet and deliver it to some url with only the data:

```
value={ "y": 2102 }
```

so i tried to create the following class:

```
class myPostReq {
    HttpResponse response = null;
    StringEntity tmp = null;
    HttpPost httpPost = null;
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient;
    HttpContext localContext;

    public myPostReq() { }
    public int post(String url,String data) {
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        localContext = new BasicHttpContext(); 
        int ret = 0;
        try {
            tmp = new StringEntity("value={ y: " + data + "}","UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            ret = -1;
        }
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httpPost.setEntity(tmp);
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);

            if (response != null) {
                ret = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ret = -2;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

however, it keeps crashing when i do the post(..) method.
I dont understand what I did wrong.

Edit: Logcat is provided:

```
02-08 18:21:51.841: W/System.err(2034): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-08 18:21:51.851: W/System.err(2034):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
02-08 18:21:51.851: W/System.err(2034):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
02-08 18:21:51.851: W/System.err(2034):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
02-08 18:21:51.861: W/System.err(2034):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
02-08 18:21:51.861: W/System.err(2034):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
02-08 18:21:51.871: W/System.err(2034):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
02-08 18:21:51.871: W/System.err(2034):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
02-08 18:21:51.871: W/System.err(2034):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
02-08 18:21:51.881: W/System.err(2034):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-08 18:21:51.881: W/System.err(2034):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-08 18:21:51.881: W/System.err(2034):     at com.example.remoteswitch.myPostReq.post(MainActivity.java:266)
02-08 18:21:51.891: W/System.err(2034):     at com.example.remoteswitch.MainActivity.startOperation(MainActivity.java:198)
02-08 18:21:51.891: W/System.err(2034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 18:21:51.891: W/System.err(2034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-08 18:21:51.891: W/System.err(2034):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3592)
02-08 18:21:51.901: W/System.err(2034):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
02-08 18:21:51.901: W/System.err(2034):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
02-08 18:21:51.901: W/System.err(2034):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-08 18:21:51.911: W/System.err(2034):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-08 18:21:51.911: W/System.err(2034):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-08 18:21:51.911: W/System.err(2034):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-08 18:21:51.921: W/System.err(2034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 18:21:51.921: W/System.err(2034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-08 18:21:51.941: W/System.err(2034):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-08 18:21:51.941: W/System.err(2034):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-08 18:21:51.941: W/System.err(2034):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-08 18:21:52.080: I/Choreographer(2034): Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-08 18:21:52.080: W/Trace(2034): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Comment: Can you post the LogCat so we can help?

Comment: just to ask...where does `localContext` get set?

Comment: ditto for `httpClient` and `httpPost`

Comment: ditto? I dont understand you sorry. What about localContext? I added logcat

Comment: ditto = same for (e.g. where do they get set?)

Answer (score 1):

You *must* be getting NullPointerException where you reference `httpPost` and `httpClient` and `localContext`. You should initialize them something like...

```
httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
// localContext = HttpSupport.getHttpContextInstance(); ???

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value", "{ y: 2102 }"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

prior to referencing them. You should also add code to check the return code in your `response` like...

```
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
   // notify user
}
```

Comment: I fixed and added all initialisations needed, now it doesn't crash but it also doesnt sends anything. I tried monitoring with wireshark. i dont see anything. I edited my class in main post

Comment: are you getting a 200 (HttpStatus.SC_OK) from the post??

Comment: why are you setting `tmp` twice...and `httpPost.setEntity(tmp);` twice? are you passing in what you think you are? you are sending the contents of `data`...is that empty?

Comment: Also...please add the check of the request's status code. if you aren't getting `HttpStatus.SC_OK` that would be interesting to know.

Comment: It was a bad type when i posted it. I took the response and returned it to a textView on screen, so i should see 200. but even without all that, i dont see the packet in wireshark, so its definitely not sent

Comment: i keep getting exception. at the part i do the try-catch for execute.

Comment: the returned value is always -2. sending the data from a normal http page works flawlessly

Comment: what exception? can you post the (small) logcat for that? (i think we're close!). put `e.printStackTrace()` prior to `ret = -2;` in the `catch()` block

Comment: all of the HttpPost examples i see do the following (for the posted data) `List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value", "{ y: 2102 }"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));`

Comment: I havent tried yet your last suggestion, im going to now. meanwhile, i updated the main post with the logcat. i also see *alot* of the last line it contains, what is it?

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException`: you can no longer do networking on the main (UI) thread. the code should be moved to, typically, `AsyncTask`. don't worry, it's fairly EZ to create/call an AsyncTask. Lots and lots of examples here on SO. http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2012/11/asynctask-android-example-asynctask-in.html is as good as any.

Comment: I see. so the main activity cant create networking, so i use an AsyncTask that does it in the background (sort of)? Ill follow both your link and the google dev description for this. thank you!

Comment: Absolutely right. AsyncTask (or any non-UI Thread) will have to be used to do networking...or you get that Exception

Comment: Ill keep digging in it tomorrow. its too late now for new things. You've been very helpful thanks

Comment: You were right. a small 20mins tweaking and it was done. working great. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It appears that neither you initialize httpPost nor you setup requestURL. Try this...

```
defaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(requestUrl);
httpResponse = defaultHttpClient.execute(httpPost);
```